# Digital Latch Circuit with Unknown Outputs

Tags: digital-logic, analog, latch

**Introduction**

I am a student currently enrolled in a digital course course. I'm actually an analog kind of individual so I (like most other analog people) have a hard time understanding logic. Anyways, here goes:

**Problem**

Here is a digital circuit that resembles a latch. I attempted to create a truth table, but found it hard to follow through towards the end. When either A or B is false, the output of the AND gates are immediately false. But when A and B are both true, I can't determine the output of the latch. It appears as if every time I follow through the wires labeling the logic value, they switch over. I'm kinda wondering if this is how clocks are made also?

[image]

**Question**

Given the circuit and truth table shown above, can anyone help me understand why the outputs of this circuit are strange when A and B are both true?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is and i don't see anything that closely resembles a clear question.

Comment: @user46450  Why such a change to the scope of this question: from memory controller to simple latch ?